# Is there an iterator method that takes a predicate and gives back an index and the matching element?

Tags: rust, iterator, position, rust-itertools

I am searching for something like this:

```rs
let iter = vec![1, 2, 40, 3].into_iter();
let (pos, elt) = iter.position_find(|&x| x > 10);
//                    ^ does not exist

println!("{pos} {elt}"); // 2 40
```

Both `Iterator::position` and `Iterator::find` advance the iterator, so I can't use both unless I'm cloning the iterator, which is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` together with [`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate):

```
let iter = vec![1, 2, 40, 3].into_iter();
if let Some((pos, elt)) = iter.enumerate().find(|(i, x)| x > &10) {
    println!("{pos} {elt}"); // 2 40
}
```

If you don't want to write this out every time, you could even turn it into an [extension trait](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0445-extension-trait-conventions.html#what-is-an-extension-trait) to automatically implement it as a method on all iterators:

```
trait FindPosition: Iterator {
    fn find_position<F: FnMut(usize, &Self::Item) -> bool>(
        &mut self,
        mut f: F,
    ) -> Option<(usize, Self::Item)> {
        self.enumerate().find(|(i, item)| f(*i, item))
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> FindPosition for I {}

fn main() {
    let mut iter = vec![1, 2, 40, 3].into_iter();
    if let Some((pos, elt)) = iter.find_position(|_, x| *x > 10) {
        println!("{pos} {elt}"); // 2 40
    }
}
```